# Exactness of short sequences of double complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Weibel defines a double complex $A_{..}$ over some abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ as the lattice $(A_{p,q},d^v,d^h)$ of entries from $\mathcal{A}$ where the rows and columns are all chain complexes over $\mathcal{A}$ and each square anti-commutes. In order to consider double complexes as chain complexes of chain complexes, Weibel introduces a sign trick where we replace $d^v_{p,q}$ with $(-1)^pd^v_{p,q}$ [as this now ensures that all the squares in the lattice commute and hence $(-1)^pd^v_{p,.}$ is chain complex map from the chain complex in the $p$-th row to the chain complex in the $p-1$-th row].

Lemma: A sequence $0\to A_.\to B_.\to C_.\to 0$ is exact iff $\forall n$, $0\to A_n\to B_n\to C_n\to 0$ is exact (this is exercise 1.2.4 in Weibel). I would like to know if something similar holds for short sequences of double complexes. Below, I have tried to make this precise and give my argument as to why this (probably) holds.

Statement: A sequence $0\to A_{..}\to B_{..}\to C_{..}\to 0$ of double complexes is exact $\iff$ $\forall p,q$, $0\to A_{p,q}\to B_{p,q}\to C_{p,q}\to 0$ is exact.

Proof: Using the sign trick we identify the given sequence of double complexes as a sequence of chain complexes of chain complexes $0\to (A_.)_*\to (B_.)_*\to (C_.)_*\to 0$, which (from the above lemma) is exact iff $0\to (A_.)_q\to (B_.)_q\to (C_.)_q\to 0$ is exact for all $q$. I shall write $(A_p)_q$ simply as $A_{p,q}$ henceforth. For each $q$ fixed, $0\to (A_.)_q\to (B_.)_q\to (C_.)_q\to 0$ is exact iff $0\to A_{p,q}\to B_{p,q}\to C_{p,q}\to 0$ is exact $\forall p$.

Does this seem right? Any suggestions will be very helpful :))

Comment: Yeah it's right, I guess you have to justify that the sign trick does not affect exactness

Comment: The question is: how do you *define* exactness of a sequence of double complexes in the first place? There is a category $Double(\mathcal{A})$ of double complexes and morphisms between them and the sign trick gives an isomorphism $Double(\mathcal{A})\cong Ch(Ch(\mathcal{A}))$. The categories are both abelian and the isomorphism is exact, so exactness in these categories are equivalent concepts, but it's your choice as to which one you wanna start doing your definitions in.

Comment: For that matter, I am not sure how to define a morphism in this category $\text{Double}(\mathcal(A)$. Thinking of each double complex as a lattice on a sheet, a double complex morphism $A\to B$ MAYBE(?) thought of as a collection of morphisms that connect each square in sheet $A$ to the corresponding square in sheet $B$ st EACH(?) face of the resulting cube either commutes or anti-commutes. Does this seem likely?

Comment: @Thorgott thanks for explaining that there is an exact invertible functor from the category of double complexes to the category of chain complexes of chain complexes. Hopefully, I have understood your comment properly?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. As you suggest, a morphism of double complexes should consist of a collection of morphisms $A_{p,q}\rightarrow B_{p,q}$ that commute with both the horizontal and vertical differentials.